# Remove the version number in the data frame in R column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

This is my original data.frame:

```
cell         counts        gene   
TGCTACC-1     10           ALKBH5
TACACGA-1     20           KDM5C
TCCTTGG-1     30           EZH2
TACGGTC-1     30           PRMT2
```

I want to remove the trailing numbers  and "-" from the `cell` column. How can I do this?

My desired output likes this:

```
cell         counts        gene   
TGCTACC       10           ALKBH5
TACACGA       20           KDM5C
TCCTTGG       30           EZH2
TACGGTC       30           PRMT2
```

Comment: Try `substr(your_data$cell, 1, 7)` assuming that there always 7 characters in that column before the `-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
sub("-.*", "", df$cell)

[1] "TGCTACC" "TACACGA" "TCCTTGG" "TACGGTC"
```